# Lagrange - intuitive understanding of formula for multiple constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, plane-geometry, gradient-flows

Say there was a function $f(x, y, z)$ constrained by $g(x, y, z) = c$.

I understand intuitively/spatially/visually why at the max or min, $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel. (I saw a very good explanation which used contour lines.)

But I'm having trouble understanding the case with multiple constraints, like:
$f(x, y, z)$ constrained by $g(x, y, z) = c$ and $h(x, y, z) = k$.

Why is $\nabla f$ in the plane spanned by $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$? ($\nabla f$ = $\lambda \nabla g$ + $\mu \nabla h$)

Aren't gradients of the same dimensions always in the same plane already? (For some 3D surface, the gradient $\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ is always in the x-y plane.) So what new information does this give us?

I do understand it when it's written out like $L(x, y, z, \lambda, \mu) = f + \lambda (g - c) + \mu (h - k)$, since when you set $\nabla L$ = 0, it will give the above equation. But I would prefer to have an intuitive/spatial/visual grasp as well.

Comment: The gradient $\nabla f$ is now a 3-dimensional vector, so it is not in the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: In continuation with @mlc, for $f(x,y,z)=0$, $\nabla f$ is the vector (normal to the surface) defined by  $ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},  \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}).$

Comment: @mlc Well what if the function was $z = f(x, y)$ and the constraints were $g(x, y) = c$ and $h(x, y) = k$? Then $\nabla f$ is $( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} )$ in the x-y plane. And $\nabla g$ is the vector normal to the contour surface g(x, y) = c, in the xy plane. Same with $\nabla h$. So since it's already clear that $\nabla f$ is in the xy plane, I don't understand what new information $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g + \mu \nabla g$ tells us...